# Role of FIFO Buffer for COM Port in windows

Tags: windows, serial-port, buffer

can anyone here please explain the role of FiFo Buffer check (at advanced COM Port settings from device manager) in windows?

How checking/unchecking the FIFO Buffer affects reading data from COM Port?

Many Thanks in advance for helpful replies!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original UART chip used in IBM-PC designs was the [8250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8250_UART).  It could store just one received byte while the receiver was busy receiving the next byte.  That puts a high demand on the responsiveness of the operating system's serial port driver, responding to the "data received" interrupt.  It must be quick enough to read that byte before the receiver overwrites it.  Not being quick enough causes an overrun error and irretrievable data loss.  High interrupt rates are also detrimental.

That design was improved upon by the [16550 UART chip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16550_UART).  It got a larger buffer, the FIFO, giving the OS more time to empty the buffer before an overrun could occur.  The serial port driver can program it to generate an interrupt at a particular fill level, thus reducing the interrupt rate as well.

But chips designs have the same kind of problem that software has, the original 16550 had a bug in the FIFO implementation.  Fixed in the 16550A, version 1.1 in software speak.

Problem was, the driver could not tell whether the machine had the buggy version of the 16550 or a good one.  Simple chips like that don't have a GetVersion() equivalent.  So it provided a property page that lets the user turn the FIFO support off, thus bypassing the bug.

The odds that today you'll have the buggy version are zero.  Turning the FIFO off is no longer necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for so nice and detailed reply Professor :)